# Laravel- Invalid Argument supplied for foreach

Tags: php, laravel

I a new to Laravel.
I am trying to display data in an html table.

Model User:

```
public function post(){
        return $this->hasMany('App/Post');
    }
```

Model Post:

```
public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App/User');
    }
```

Code in Dashboard:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$post->title}}</td>
                            <td><a href="/posts/{{$post->id/edit}}">Edit</a></td>    
                        </tr>
                   @endforeach
```

I get the error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Can someone help out? Thank you in advance

Comment: Does the `public function post` return an object with many posts? If yes, try calling it `public function posts`.

Comment: Did you `dd($posts)` before your `@foreach`? What does it show?

Comment: can you do a `var_dump($posts)` before the foreach to see what youre getting?

Comment: What is the does the $posts data structure look like?

Comment: Is there conflict between post(), $post, $posts, and posts ?

Comment: @benny-ben yeah, i tried. Didn't worked

Comment: @AnnaJeanine still gives the same error

Comment: @SherylHohman No, there is no Conflict

Comment: @kerbholz I'm sorry, i am new to laravel, idk what does dd means

Comment: According to [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-dd) "The dd function dumps the given variables and ends execution of the script"

Comment: @kerbholz `dd($posts)` won't work in the blade. @AshFixed remove the foreach loop and `var_dumo($posts)` to let us know the structure of the `$posts`, else no one can help you.

Comment: @AnnaJeanine Well, yes, it's `{{ dd($posts) }}` in blade. `var_dumo($posts)` won't work either ;)

Comment: @AnnaJeanine $post has id->int, title, body,created_at, updated_at,user_id

Comment: @kerbholz I meant `var_dump` :)

Comment: @AshFixed it may have all those attributes, but are they being passed to the blade correctly? If you do a ` var_dump` you'll see that you're not passing an array. That is where the problem is.

Comment: @AnnaJeanine, Yeah, there is an error here. It is giving null. But, why, the relationship is setup properly

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you help me to rectify this too?

Comment: @benny-ben, It worked!! Thanks man. But can you tell why that happened

Comment: I miss a fundamental passage to the question: what have you set in the variable posts `$posts = ...;`?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<td><a href="/posts/{{$post->id/edit}}">Edit</a></td>
```

to:

```
<td><a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}/edit">Edit</a></td>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is related to an `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error?

Comment: I have added /edit too go to edit page, if i don't it would take me to index page

Comment: I have changed the code. You surely don't have an `id/edit` property in your model, so move `/edit` after double curly braces.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped you, please mark it as answer.